# Flowable.fromPublisher expects a Publisher, then why does it accept a Subscriber?

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

The method signature is:

```
public static <T> Flowable<T> fromPublisher(Publisher<? extends T> source) {...}
```

But if I write this code, it somehow works:

```
Flowable<String> flowable = Flowable.fromPublisher(subscriber -> {
  subscriber.onNext("But onNext belongs in a subscriber...");
  subscriber.onNext("Which means I am passing a subscriber instead of a publisher");
  subscriber.onNext("What's happening?");
  subscriber.onComplete();
});
```

I know I'm not looking at this correctly. Can someone explain how passing a `Subscriber` instead of a `Publisher` works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bit:

```java
subscriber -> {
  subscriber.onNext("But onNext belongs in a subscriber...");
  subscriber.onNext("Which means I am passing a subscriber instead of a publisher");
  subscriber.onNext("What's happening?");
  subscriber.onComplete();
}
```

Is a lambda expression, and is an implementation of `Publisher`. Your code is equivalent to the following (which uses an anonymous class):

```
Flowable<String> flowable = Flowable.fromPublisher(new Publisher<String>() {
  @Override
  public void subscribe(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {
    subscriber.onNext("But onNext belongs in a subscriber...");
    subscriber.onNext("Which means I am passing a subscriber instead of a publisher");
    subscriber.onNext("What's happening?");
    subscriber.onComplete();
  }
});
```

Comment: Oh interesting! So it's an anonymous class defined through a lambda expression. I don't think I've seen this before. Is there documentation or any concrete examples like this I can read up on?

Comment: [This Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) covers lambda expressions (and method references). A lambda expression is essentially shorthand when defining an implementation of a "functional interface". A functional interface is an interface that has exactly one abstract method (e.g. `Publish`, whose single abstract method is `#subscribe(Subscriber)`). If you research _functional interface_, _lambda expression_, and _method reference_ (within the context of Java) you should be able to find any clarification you need.

Comment: @ritratt The introduction of lambdas in Java 8 represented a major change in language style (things that were previously too cumbersome to represent became usable), so if you want to read any modern Java code, you need to become familiar with them.